# Does it converges to $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, gamma-distribution

I have to show that this expression zero $\frac{\log(\bar{F}(p^{-1}(x_n))}{n(1-x_n)^2} \to 0$ for $n\to \infty$, where F is the cdf of a gamma distribution with scale $k\cdot \alpha$ and rate $\frac{\beta}{a}$.
After
$p^{-1}(x_n) = bs\sqrt{\log n}-d$, where $b$ and $s$ is postive constant between $0$ and $1$, and $d$ is a positive constants.

Let $x_n = \Phi(s\sqrt{\log n})$ ,  hence $x_n \to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.

Can anyone help me with that?

Here is my thoughts:

Using a result from my lecture notes we know that $n(1-x_n)^2 \sim \frac{c^2n}{s^2\log(n)}\exp(-s\sqrt{\log n})^2$ for $n\to \infty$.

($f(x_n)\sim g(x_n)$ means that $\frac{f(x_n)}{g(x_n)}\to 1$ for $n\to \infty$)

We have now an expression for the denominator (for large $n$). But I cant find a similar expression for the numerator, because we firstly have to find $\bar{F}=1-F$ and this is very challenging because of the integral of a gamma density is not easy to integrate.

Can anyone help me with the numerator or maybe just got a better idea?
Lhospital could maybe be an easier way to show that the expression in first line goes to $0$?

Comment: Is $p(t)=\Phi(b(t+d))$? And I presume that $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt$ ?

Comment: The p-function is actually the default probability but $p^{-1}(x_n)$ is defined as in the question, which is stated in the paper I am looking at. I think it is enough to answer my question :) 
Yes, this is the definition of the cumulative distributions function of standard normal